# Is the value of i getting copied to the next lexical environment? I'm confused

Tags: javascript

I don't quite understand whats happening in the code,why only value 1 is getting printed.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i));
  i++;
}
```

Comment: If anyone tries this in the console, you’ll probably see `0` and `1` in the console, but keep in mind that `0` is not _logged_, it is the return value. Only `1` is actually logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `let` works in `for` loops is that for each loop iteration, a **separate** variable is created; this is primarily so closures in loops like yours are less complicated than they used to be. So keeping that in mind:

1. You start with `i = 0`.
2. Since `0 < 2`, the first loop body executes using that copy of `i`.
3. You schedule a callback logging that copy of `i`.
4. Then you increment `i` with the `i++;` at the end of the loop body. Now, that copy of `i` has the value `1`.
5. Then when the `for` loop's increment section is done, a **second** `i` is created, given the value of the first one (`1`), and then incremented. So the second `i` has the value `2`.
6. Since `2 < 2` is false, the loop stops.
7. Later, the calback scheduled in Step #3 executes, logging the value of the first `i` (`1`).

This is fundamentally different from how that code would act if you used `var` instead of `let`, and is one of the reasons `let` is so handy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `setTimeOut` method runs after the loop ends. In your case you are incrementing the value again in the loop, and therefore after that the let scope gives the value of `i` which is `1` now.

Do something like this instead:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i));
}
```